# Checkbox control doesn't accept value on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies, checkbox

I have the below JS on my _Layout.cshtml.  Basically on every "Page Load" the checkbox is getting  set to Checked(true) even though the code should set it to the Cookie.
If I just set it to false on Page Load it works.(e.g.`$("#ShowInactive").prop("checked", false);`) But, as you can see in the code, I'm able to set the value of the checkbox in the Click event based of the Cookie.

I have alse tried having the function be `$(document).ready(function () {` but noting was different.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        console.log('1 - ' + Cookies.get('ShouldShowInactive'));
        var Inactive = Cookies.get('ShouldShowInactive') == true ? true : false;
        $("#ShowInactive").prop("checked", Inactive);

        $("#ShowInactive").click(function () {
            console.log('2 - ' + Cookies.get('ShouldShowInactive'));
            var ShowInactive = this.checked ? true : false;
            console.log('3 - ' + ShowInactive);
            Cookies.set('ShouldShowInactive', ShowInactive);
            console.log('4 - ' + Cookies.get('ShouldShowInactive'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Checkbox control:

```
<div class="pull-right checkbox">
   <label class="btn btn-success">
       @(Html.Kendo().CheckBox().Name("ShowInactive").Label("Show Inactive"))
   </label>
</div>
```

When I inspect the cookie, through my `Console.log()` and through Chrome Dev Tools the value is always shown as `true` or `false`. Also, before the above way I was trying to set it straight to `Cookies.get('ShouldShowInactive')` Basically the one way the check box was always checked on Page Load and the current way it's always unchecked.  Both ways ignoring the correct value of the Cookie.

Comment: does the Cookies.get() function return a string or boolean?

Comment: I think this doesn't matter since the `Inactive` var is set to be a boolean in anyway => `? true : false`

Comment: @TCHdvlp `"true" == true` would return false

Comment: It returns a string I believe. I'm using js-cookie(https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).  @tihom I'll try changing `== true` to `=="true"`

Comment: @tihom wow, that's what happens when you stare at something too long and convince yourself strange things are happening.  You miss the obvious...thanks.  Works like a charm now!

Comment: @RefractedPaladin cool that it solved your problem, added it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cookies.get()` function returns a string and `"true" == true` would evaluate to false. Change the condition to

```
 var Inactive = Cookies.get('ShouldShowInactive') == "true" ? true : false;
```